# C compiling and running

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, gcc, terminal

I'm new in C and I'm trying to run a simple helloworld, but the terminal is not displaying the output.
Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm trying to compile, I run the command

```
gcc hello.c -o hello.exe
```

But it is not displaying the phrase. Am I missing something? I have installed the ucrt64 environment and the gcc compiler in vscode.

Comment: You need to execute the program that `gcc` created. Type `hello` on the command prompt, right after the `gcc ...` command

Comment: Programming in C is split into multiple steps: 1) Edit the source; 2) Build the source into object files; 3) Link object files and libraries to create the executable program; And 4) Run the program. Step 2 and 3 can be combines (like it is with your command), so you're missing step 4: Running the program. Try `./hello.exe` after the command to build the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line `gcc hello.c -o hello.exe` constructs the executable file **hello.exe**. You must execute this program to see its output by typing `hello`, `./hello.exe` or `.\hello.exe` at the shell prompt, depending on the operating system and command line interpreter used for your tests.

Note also these remarks:

- you must include the `<stdio.h>` header
- you should add a trailing newline to ensure proper output on all systems.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And since you do not use the command line arguments, you could simplify the code as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If the `gcc` command does not create the executable file without even complaining about any errors doing so, I'm afraid the compiler setup seems to be broken. Try and reinstall the compiler or use a different system if possible.

Comment: I would add that there's no point in having `argc` and `argv` in the main function.

Comment: @Surge: correct. Answer amended with an simpler alternative.

Comment: The compiler setup seems to be broken.  Try and reinstall the compiler or use a different system if possible.

Comment: so essentially the compiler was the problem, reinstalled it and worked like a charm. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @Leo_Miche: let's clean up the comments :)